# Modelling an efficiency drop of machine after certain hours of work

Tags: optimization, conditional-statements, linear-programming, cplex, ampl

I am building linear programming model of machines manufacturing some parts in AMPL using CPLEX solver.

My problem is how to model 10% efficiency step drop of machine after 100 hours of work. I know that proper approach in my case is to use binary variable. Unfortunately I have no idea how to manage this.

Could you show an example how to model described above behavior in linear programming?

**EDIT: attaching current AMPL code**

Data:

```
data;

param M := 3; # machines count
param N := 5; # parts count

param efficiency: # efficiency [pc / h]
        1       2       3       4       5   :=
    1   0.85    1.30    0.65    1.50    0.40
    2   0.65    0.80    0.55    1.50    0.70
    3   1.20    0.95    0.35    1.70    0.40;

param R :=  1 45 # machines costs [usd / h]
            2 35
            3 40;

param C :=  1 60 # minimal manufactured counts of particulat parts
            2 60
            3 60
            4 120
            5 120;
```

Model:

```
model;

param M; # machines count
param N; # parts count
param efficiency {1..M, 1..N}; # efficiency [pc / h]

param R {1..M}; # machines costs [usd / h]
param C {1..N}; # minimal manufactured counts of particulat parts

var t {1..M, 1..N}; # time[machine,part]
var d {n in 1..N} = sum {m in 1..M} t[m,n] * efficiency[m,n];

minimize cost: sum {m in 1..M, n in 1..N} R[m] * t[m,n];

subject to c1 {n in 1..N}:
  d[n] >= C[n];

subject to t1 {m in 1..M}:
  sum {n in 1..N} t[m,n] <= 180; # machine time must be less than 180

subject to t2 {m in 1..M, n in 1..N}:
  t[m,n] >= 0; # times must non-negative
```

Comment: Show us your current model.

Comment: I have just modified original post. Code current model + data attached.

Comment: Just splitting into two machines should work.

Comment: Sounds like workaround.

Comment: Does the machine drop in efficiency after it has been scheduled for 100 hours or after 100 hours have passed (regardless of the machine's use, as might happen if workers/operators become less efficient).